# apply session struct to req context

Tags: go

I want to apply a struct with session data and methods

```
type session struct {
    lock            sync.Mutex
    Expires         int
}

func (s *session) Write(){
    
}

func (s *session) Close(){
    
}
```

The session struct is applied to `r *http.Request` content. `*sess` is a pointer

```
ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), session{}, sess)
r   = r.WithContext(ctx)
```

Then how to access it from the request handler function?

```
func Session(r *http.Request) *session {
    fields := r.Context().Value(session{}).(interface{})
    return fields
}
```

error

```
cannot use fields (variable of type interface{}) as *session value in return statement: need type assertion
```

## update

In my `sess` module I have the following two functions

```
func Session(r *http.Request) *session {
    s, _ := r.Context().Value(session{}).(*session)
    return s
}

func Start(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *session {
    // Creating the session in variable "s"
    
    ctx := r.Context()
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, session{}, s)
    r2 := r.WithContext(ctx)
    *r = *r2
    
    return s
}
```

In the main where the handler for the request is located

```
h.Route(serv.ALL, "/set", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    s1 := sess.Start(w, r)
    
    fmt.Println("expires:",s1.Expires)
    
    fmt.Println(sess.Session(r).Expires)
})
```

Why is the output from `sess.Session(r)` `nil` when `sess.Start(w, r)` returns the session?

Comment: `r.WithContext(ctx)` returns a shallow copy of `r`; reassigning that copy to the variable will not change the caller's variable, of which `r` is also a shallow copy. Say for example: if `r` was an integer (which essentially that's what a pointer is), and inside `Start` you did `r = 123`, would you then expect the caller of `Start` to see that change after `Start` exited? See https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators for the clue to the solution you seek.

Comment: @mkopriva could you please post an example? :)

Comment: `r2 := r.WithContext(ctx)`; `*r = *r2`

Comment: @mkopriva have updated `func Start()` in my question.  `sess.Session(r)` still returns `nil`

Comment: Your key, i.e. `session{}` is weird, I'm not sure it is the problem but it could be. Have you tried with the conventional (using a type _scalar_) as shown [here](https://pkg.go.dev/context@go1.21.0#example-WithValue) (notice the `favContextKey`)?

Comment: see here: https://go.dev/play/p/aJYXSDYPwtQ, it works as advertised.

Comment: @mkopriva great! it works. It was the key :) create an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Since in your case, you're sure that session value in the context is of type `*session`, you just have to cast `fields` to `*session`:

```golang
func Session(r *http.Request) *session {
    fields := r.Context().Value(session{}).(*session)
    return fields
}
```

You can even add an extra check to be **sure** you have a value, and it's of type `*session`:

```golang
func Session(r *http.Request) *session {
    fields, ok := r.Context().Value(session{}).(*session)
    if !ok {
        panic("not a session or no session")
    }
    return fields
}
```

**But**, as your comment suggests, you also have to manage the case where the session is `nil`; also, instead of panicking, I highly recommend to return also a `bool` value so the caller manages the case when there is no session in the context. If the `bool` is `false`, the caller must not expect a valid session:

```golang
func Session(r *http.Request) (*session, bool) {
    s, ok := r.Context().Value(session{}).(*session)
    if s == nil { // if session is nil, return false
        return s, false
    }
    return s, ok
}
```

Then, with that last `Session` method, you can write something like this:

```golang
func main() {
    sess := &session{Expires: 123456789}
    r := &http.Request{}

    ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), session{}, sess)

    r = r.WithContext(ctx)

    s, hasSession := Session(r)

    if hasSession { // this only makes sense to use the session if there is a session
        fmt.Println("session found in ctx")
        fmt.Println(s.Expires)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("no session found in ctx")
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
session found in ctx
123456789
```

See https://go.dev/play/p/bIvM9FfSla1 for a full working example.

Comment: Have updated my question. Everything seems to work fine until I reach the line `fmt.Println(Session(r).Expires)` ..... `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

Comment: @clarkk I have updated my answer, hope that helps. In a nutshell, you were facing the `nil pointer dereference` because there were no session inside your context. The edited answer shows how to deal with `nil` values.

Comment: have updated my question

Comment: My answer was for your initial question, but if you change the question, then my answer becomes invalid :/ @mkopriva answered in the comments for your second issue, I guess it's related to your key.